# Why is this function entire? $f(z) = z^{-1} \sin{z} \exp(i tz)$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

In problem 10.44 of Real & Complex Analysis, the author says $f(z) = z^{-1} \sin{z} \exp(i tz)$ is entire without explaining why. My guess is that $z = 0$ is a removable singularity, $f(z) = 1$ and $f'(z) = 0$, but I cannot seem to prove it from the definitions of limit and derivative. The definition of derivative gives:
$$
\left|\dfrac{\sin z \exp(itz)}{z^2}\right|
$$

Is my intuition correct? How can I prove that the above goes to $0$ as $z \to 0$?

Comment: The exponential $e^{itz}$ is entire, so you only need to check if $\sin z/z$ is entire.  This should be a little easier.

Comment: The function $z\mapsto z^{-1}\sin z$ is entire. Think about the Taylor expansion of $\sin$, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said $z=0$ is a removable singularity, but the value which removes the singularity is not $f(0)=0$. That is why you run into that problem.

The easiest way to see that that is entire is the following:

$$g(z)=\sin(z) \exp(itz)$$

is entire. Write its power series $$g(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...$$

Since $g(0)=0$ you have $a_0=0$. But then you get a Taylor series for $f(z)$ ;)

Comment: PS. If you know that $f,g$ are entire, then you know that $\frac{f}{g}$ is analityc at all points where $g$ is not zero. At the points $z_0$ where $g=0$, the above argument shows immediately that $\frac{f}{g}$ is analytic if and only if $z_0$ is a zero of same or higher multiplicity for $f$ than for $g$.

Comment: Thanks for outlining a general approach to this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $u:z\mapsto\sin(z)/z$ is indeed entire since $u(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nz^{2n}/(2n+1)!$ has an infinite radius of convergence. Multiplying $u$ by the exponential, also entire, does not change anything.

Comment: Ah right. I thought of manipulating the Taylor expansion of $\exp$ in this manner. I should have tried it with $\sin$. Thanks! Is there a general method for such problems or is it always on case-by-case basis? I can open a new question if there is a general method, but I doubt it.

Comment: @Henry The particular Taylor expansion is actually irrelevant, as you can see in my answer. This means that this type of manipulations can be done in general.